Websocket client not connecting using .net core 7 over vpn
I've a websocket client (Clientwebsocket) in .net 6 and it's connecting to the server both using vpn and without vpn. Server is having public IP. I want to upgrade this to .net 7, but when I do it doesn't connect over vpn. It connects without vpn. I tried setting the remote certificate validation to always return true and it has no effect. I'm getting failed to establish connection to server error.
Adding code sample
using System.Net.WebSockets;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

try
{
   var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
   ws.Options.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

    await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://.../websocket", UriKind.Absolute), CancellationToken.None);

    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}


could you please add more detail with code snippets ?
